# Twitter login using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, twitter-login

I want to add a twitter login functionality for my website using only JavaScript and HTML.

is it possible ?

Comment: you need backend code too or you mean only from the client

Comment: @arisalexis no i just want to fill a form email and name

Comment: passport.js is the easiest option imo

Answer (score 4):

Yes and no.

It is not possible at the time of writing, if you want to do it only with browser client side javascript, because twitter does not allow cross site requests.

Browsers execute javascript code in a sandbox environment, which does not allow you to do a request to another domain as yours, except the 3rd party domain explicitly allows it. This is called [Http Access Control (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

However the twitter api can of course be consumed by a javascript app, which is not running in a browser.

So if you want this functionality for your website and you want to code it only in javascript, you would have to write a backend api for your website in nodejs or use another 3rd party service like @RationalDev suggested

Answer (score 4):

If you mean only JavaScript and HTML on the client, there are some third party libraries.

Auth0 is popular and has [instructions for Twitter](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/social/twitter).

Another possible solution is to use Firebase auth. It has a [JavaScript API which can be used as follows](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/twitter-login#redirect-mode):

> Create an instance of the Twitter provider object:

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider();
```

> Authenticate with Firebase using the Twitter provider object. You can prompt your users to sign in with their Twitter accounts either by opening a pop-up window or by redirecting to the sign-in page.

Comment: Will use a 3d party auth service in between (because not possible otherwise) , which you have to give your twitter api secrets to, but i vote it up, because it essentially allows to do what the OP want.

Comment: Thanks didn't know google has this platform "firebase" btw this should be accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

This javascript snippet is a working example of how to do this. You can try it and tweak it: https://jsfiddle.net/s3egg5h7/43/

As pointed out, a Javascript-only solution requires a 3rd-party service, in this case https://oauth.io.

Even if you do not want to use the 3rd-party service, the snippet is useful since you do not have to write any code to test out Twitter APIs to see they return what you need

It is pretty short:

```
$('#twitter-button').on('click', function() {
    // Initialize with your OAuth.io app public key
    OAuth.initialize('OAUTH_IO_KEY');
    // Use popup for OAuth
    OAuth.popup('twitter').then(twitter => {
        console.log('twitter:', twitter);
        // Retrieves user data from OAuth provider by using #get() and
        // OAuth provider url    
        twitter.get('/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json?include_email=true').then(data => {
            console.log('self data:', data);
        })    
    });
})
```

It requires a few external references, e.g., bootstrap css, oauthio javascript open-source library, etc.

I think using a 3rd-party service may make sense since it hides all the inconsistencies in the OAuth implementation of different providers, like Twitter, Facebook, etc.

I did not create this code so for attribution purposes, please refer to: https://coderwall.com/p/t46-ta/javascript-twitter-social-login-button-for-oauth

Answer (score 0):

If you check the twitter's api documentation, you can see how to do the login.

I think your question is how insert a plugin to login similar than facebook but I think they don't did any library.

When the user clicks the loggin button you must send a post request to twitter to get the oauth_token:
Example: POST request to "api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"

and then, twitter provides you the oauth_token and the oauth_token_secret (private).

Once you did this step you must to redirect the user to twitter.
Example: GET request to "api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN_GIVEN_IN_STEP_1"

If everything has gone well twitter response you with the oauth_token and a verifier oauth token.

Let's set up the last step!

Send a post request to twitter api endpoint with the verifier oauth token provided in the response of step 2.
Example: POST request to "api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token" sending the verifier oauth token as post parameter.

And then twitter response with a secret token and the user token, you can save it and feel free to use it in any twitter endpoint.

Login documentation: https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in/implementing
Browser auth flow: https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in/desktop-browser

Regards!

Comment: to get `auth_token` while post request what are the parameters to be passed along with API ?